# please help me .. can any one solve this problem usingg NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

solve for dependent variable f and theta. where m and n are parameters
please help me.

```
Eqn1 = n*(-f''[x])^(n - 1)f'''[x] - mf'[x]^2 + 
     (m*(2*n-1)+1)/(n+1)f[x]f''[x]  == 0; 

Eqn2 = n(-theta'[x])^(n - 1)theta''[x] + 
 (m(2 n - 1) + 1)/(n + 1)f[x]theta'[x] -mf'[x]theta[x]==0; 

BC1 = f[0] == 0; BC2 = f'[0] == 1; BC3 = f'[infinity] == 0; 
BC4 = theta[0] == 1; BC5 = theta[infinity] == 0;
```

whera m,n, parameters

param1 = {n -> 1.2}

```
sol[m_]:=NDSolve[{n(-f''[x])^(n - 1)f'''[x] - mf'[x]^2 + (m(2n-1)+1)/(n+1)f[x]f''[x] + M2^2f'[x] == 0, 
    n(-theta'[x])^(n - 1)theta''[x] + (m(2 *n - 1) + 1)/(n + 1)*f[x]theta'[x] -mf'[x]*theta[x]==0,
  BC1,BC2,BC3,BC4,BC5}/. param1, {f, theta}, {x, 0, infinity}]
```

with

```
m = {0.8, 1.2, 2.0};
```

so that

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[x] /. (sol /@ m)], {x, 0, infinity}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

produces something?

Comment: What is mf[x] in this set of equations?

Comment: Steffen jaesschke ... m is the parameter and f is the function of x..